# Access parent site list data via LINQ from subsite

Tags: 2010, list, asp.net, linq, data

I have an SP 2010 web part that access list data using LINQ.  The data and the web part currently live on the top-level site.  Would I be able to easily access that data in a different web part from a direct subsite?  When I say easily, I mean without a total overhaul of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can get the `SPWeb` using `OpenWeb()` method and then pass the `SubSiteName`

```
using(SPWeb web = sites.OpenWeb("subsiteurl"))
```

Comment: Wouldn't I want to be opening the parent web? This code would be running on the subsite.

Comment: Ok in that case you can pass the parent web url to openWeb method